# If ID contains Javascript

Tags: javascript, multiple-columns, ids

I have following JS

```
    var slider = new Slider("#testslider", {
        tooltip: 'always'
    });
```

To style my bootstrap slider by ID.
I want to style every slider in that area so I tried to put them all in one DIV like:

```
<div id="testslider">
//all sliders
</div>
```

That will only style the first slider.

I tried `[id^="testslider"]` and named every slider in this scheme: testslider1, testslider2 etc.

But that will only style the first slider.
Now with **document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="testslider"]`);** I could select all IDs but I can't figure out how to put that into

```
var slider = new Slider("#testslider", {
    tooltip: 'always'
});
```

Comment: *"...named every slider in this scheme: testslider1, testslider2 etc"*: that is bad practice. Don't use `id` for this. Instead give the same class name to all those sliders and select by class.

Comment: I know and I use this codepen https://codepen.io/riyos94/pen/NXBvEX but I can't find the classname..

Comment: add a class '.slider' and use that

Comment: You didn't define (CSS) classes for those sliders in that snippet. There is only one `class` attribute in your code and it is not on a slider.

Comment: @Lk77 if I would do that, he won't take the full style of the slider

Comment: well i don't see why it would, you add a new class, you can even call it .my-slider or .custom-slider to avoid collison with bootstrap, base style should work fine, and you just add your own style on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now with document.querySelectorAll([id^="testslider"]); I could select all IDs but I can't figure out how to put that into

```
var slider = new Slider("#testslider", {
  tooltip: 'always'
});
```

I suppose you absolutely need the `id` to instanciate the tooltip plugin...
Use a loop to go through each elements, get it's specific `id` to instancitate the slider:

```
const allSliders = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="testslider"]'));
console.log("allSliders length:", allSliders.length)

allSliders.forEach((element) => {
  console.log("id for tooltip:", "#"+element.id)  // To check if the right ids are used
  new Slider("#"+element.id, {  // The specific id is used here
    tooltip: 'always'
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to be the right thing but it won't work, and I don't get any error messages..

Comment: I added a console.log, so you can check if the right ids are used. And I fixed a tiny typo AND some missing quote.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Is there any possible way to get if the slider is active in jquery or javascript to change the class of a other object ? like $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($('testslider').hasClass('active')) { } }); because I tried and it won't work, maybe because the classes and ID's change once all IDs are executed ?

Comment: Not sure to get the question. What I provided you is a loop to instanciate all slider elements on page load. Then, what may add an *active* class to it is unknown to me. Maybe the plugin you use... Maybe some of your code. -- Write another detailled question about it.